What laptop should I get as a broke computer science student?
I'm an undergraduate CS student at a community college, I haven't gone very far into the major yet so I don't know exactly what type of hardware I would need. So far the only thing I'm really looking for is a laptop that's cheap, portable, and has a desktop interface (Windows). Is there anything else that I should be taking into consideration? I don't really know much about computers yet and I'm not planning on using it for gaming or anything like that, so I don't know if it needs good graphics or to be powerful or anything like that.

Try to get a used laptop for cheap (or even free). If you have money left over, upgrade the boot drive (C: on Windows) to a new SSD, and replace the battery if necessary. You may need to get a Windows 10 ISO since Windows 11 is not compatible with a lot of old PC hardware. Most anything that can run Windows will get you through programming in any language.
Once you have some schooling under your belt, try running Linux on your laptop. It will provide better performance on old hardware and give you some learning opportunities that can help you get ahead of your courses.

If you are not particularly committed to the Windows roach motel, many laptops which cannot run modern Windows any longer are available dirt cheap on the second-hand market. Try a low-overhead Linux distro like Lubuntu (or something more experimental like wattOS).
For "real" development work involving a compiler etc, you will eventually want top-of-the line hardware; but to get started at least enough to know what you want, a lightweight distro can get you pretty far (perhaps all the way if you are more into scripting languages like Python or Ruby, or web programming with Javascript-based stacks).

I would suggest that a cost-effective option is a Dell Inspiron 15. Currently priced at $750. It has some good specs: Intel Core i7 processor, 16GB of memory, and a 1TB SSD. It should be capable of handling most coding, development, and basic computational tasks you'll encounter as an undergrad and developer.

Long live Thinkpads! (anecdotal)
Old Thinkpads were built well and run for a very long time. It gets me through all of my projects. I am a big x230 Thinkpad but many exist and many may fit your needs better. Ebay is always a great place to purchase laptops for fairly cheap (many are refurbished and look good as new).
Here are some great recommendations:

https://www.reddit.com/r/thinkpad/comments/1e56i68/which_thinkpad_should_a_computer_science_major_get/


Welcome SpreadingKindness (wonderful name BTW)! In general, when providing a link, it's best to summarize the link's contents in your answer so that if the link stops working, you answer will still be useful.  So perhaps you can add a little summary to this answer.  Thanks, and again, welcome!

For me, one of the best cost efficient choice is the HP Pavilion 15-eh3016nf. It's portable have enough performance for the firsts years of CS.
It's a popular choice so if needed you'll find all the tutorials to upgrade the storage or change the ram. Upgrading somes components is always cheaper.
The only conns if you want to upgrade it is that the ram is in 2x8go so you cant just buy another 16go ram stick.
If the performance start being too low, i would recommend either to switch to a bigger disk and install a dual boot (ubuntu for dev / windows for Backup in case you need to use a Windows only app).
Or just to keep your actual disk and switch to Ubuntu (choose whatever distro you want but to get started i recommend Fedora or Ubuntu)
You can find it at a decent price (under 550) on the HP website with Student discount.
